# Calling class function in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, foreach

I'm using jQuery and wrote the following code:

```
function Test() {
    this.value = '';
    this.someFunction = function() {
        // do something
    }
    this.loopFunction = function() {
        var array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
        array.foreach(function() {
            // calling someFunction not possible because 'this' is defined as value of loop
            this.someFunction();
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is that i can't call the function someFunction in the loop because the keyword 'this' is now defined as value of the loop. Is there a way to do this without loosing this 'class' stucture?

Comment: This is a standard closure issue. Use a local var to save the previous `this`.

Comment: Simple but effective. Thank you

Comment: The other problem with `bind` is you lose the local `this` (the array element) which you might also want to access at the same time (although that is passed to the function as a parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard closure issue. Use a local var to save the previous `this`.

```
this.loopFunction = function() {
    vat self = this;
    var array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    array.foreach(function() {
        // calling someFunction not possible because 'this' is defined as value of loop
        self.someFunction();
    });
}
```

in some versions of jQuery you can use `bind`, but I find this far simpler to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use native [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method. For example:

```
array.foreach(function() {
    // calling someFunction not possible because 'this' is defined as value of loop
    this.someFunction();
}.bind(this));
```